# What does [String] mean in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

Does anybody know what does the following construct mean:

```
    Dim s1 as [String]
```

What do the square brackets mean? And why does the following statement with Integer fail while the one above, with String works?

```
    Dim i1 as [Integer]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

THe square brackets is used so that the compiler interprets it as a type, even if it would be a keyword. Imagine for example if you had a class named `As`:

```
Dim a As [As]
```

This is usually only used in auto generated code, so that it works with any type that you throw at it.

The reason that you can't use `[Integer]` is that `Integer` is not a data type, it's a keyword. You would have to use the corresponding data type, i.e. `[Int32]`.

Answer (score 6):

Square brackets are used to create a variable that has the same name as a keyword in VB.NET. So they are more often used that way:

```
Dim [Integer] As Integer
Dim [String] As String
```

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the other answers:

For the case of using variable names with names the same as types: you *shouldn't* have to use those in your own code. If you do, you are naming your variable names incredibly poorly, and need to work on using better variable names first!