# what do the square brakets mean in vb.net in this string

Tags: .net, vb.net, variables, specifications, square-bracket

What do the square brakets mean in vb.net in this variable below defining as [String]

```
Dim client As New WebClient()
Dim htmlCode As [String] = client.DownloadString("http://www.stackoverflow.com")
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does \[String\] mean in VB.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198442/what-does-string-mean-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's useless in your example. Brackets are there to use reserved keywords for what they aren't, for example

```
Dim [String] = "asdf"
```

which will create a var named "String" (which is stupid, but...)

Comment: great thanks - it happened because I used a c# to VB.net converter

Answer (score 2):

It allows you to use a reserved word in your code. There is some mis-information about this as some examples on the MS site use square brackets where they are not needed (In the example you gave the square brackets do not do anything)

As an example I recently wanted to use `lat` and `long` as arguments to a function:

```
Public Function CalcPosition(ByVal lat as Double, ByVal long as Double) as Double
```

This will not compile because Long is a reserved word but I can do this instead:

```
Public Function CalcPosition(ByVal lat as Double, ByVal [long] as Double) as Double
```